# Why didn't I get back my previous score in a particular tag after suspension period ends?

Tags: discussion, support, tag-score

Today, my suspension period ends so I get back my previous reputation but I didn't get back my previous score in some particular tags.

My question is:

When I get back the previous score in a particular tag? Or if I won't get back the score then what is the reason behind it?

Comment: You get all your rep back after a suspension, unless some of your posts were deleted. Which may have happened as a lead-up to your suspension. Asking this question will surely get a moderator to spill the beans.

Comment: How much reputation do you miss? Have you checked your [reputation history](http://stackoverflow.com/users/5691402/argapk?tab=reputation)? There you can see that you lost 120 reputation, because a user was removed.

Comment: guys, the question is about score in a particular tag, and it is not about reputation/suspension/any thing else.

Comment: What tags were you thinking of here? Suspensions do *not* affect tag scores; the votes on your answers to (and those are not set to 0 during a suspension).

Comment: @MartijnPieters Thanks but i know this However i didn't see any of my score in java/jsf/primefaces. before suspension there is a score in these tags but now there is zero. Why is this so?

Comment: @ArgaPK: `jsf/primefaces/stream`, actually. See my answer.

Answer (score 9):

Suspensions do not affect tag scores; answer scores do. Also, tag scores are recalculated once a day.

During your suspension [one of your answers](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/42027795/view-pdf-through-streamedcontent-send-null-value/42052671#42052671) was downvoted twice, and it was deleted today (by you). So *tomorrow*, the tag scores for the [jsf](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/jsf), [primefaces](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/primefaces) and [stream](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/tagged/stream) will go up by two points as those tag scores are recalculated and the negative score of that one answer no longer counts. *Today*, the -2 score of that answer still counts, putting the score of those 3 tags at 0.